# WCF - Is it even possible to test that WCF security encryption etc indeed takes place?

Tags: wcf

I know everywhere in tech docs there is a bunch of WCF configuration options defined, such as transport, message mode, encrypted messages, ssl, https, certificates, reliable transfer... bla bla bla

But, for me these are just words with no proof at all. They say if you dont implement these security features, hackers or whoever they are can intercept WCF call and get the data.

My question is - how can I as a developer SEE with my eyes (and not just blindly trust to whatever they say without understanding what they are saying) that whatever is passed between the client and WCF service is indeed secure if I apply some config parameters and insecure if I don't apply them?

Is it even possible? 
I wasnt able to find ANY information on the internet related to that. NONE.

For instance, why should I use https instead of http, why should I define Transport for endoint config, which by itself has various number of weird settings that mean nothing to me, I cant see with my eyes that these setting take any effect.

I need to see proof. In Firefox using Firebug, I have a webclient default.aspx page that calls a wcf service, passing a string and wcf returns "Hello" + string, no matter what I specify, I see values passed in clear text, although wcf is using https.

Thanks.

Comment: Try something like e.g. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Don't rely on tools (like Firebug) that are built inside the client - the client that's already *meant* to be able to decrypt the messages it receives.

Comment: This question doesn't really deal with any specific programming problem. It's more related to networking matters, and possibly security matters, such that I can't pick a decent other site to recommend either. But there are entire multi-day courses teaching things like "ethical hacking" that you'd need to undertake to understand all of the protections and why they're used.


Comment: Also, everyone is entitled to his/her opinion. However, saying that these are words with no proof, when in reality people have spent years dveloping and demonstrating the efficiency and effectiveness (through cryptanalysis among other things) of their solutions and published reviewed papers might be a little too closed minded and offensive

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. Please note the whole phrase, not a part of it - I was saying these are just word with no proof FOR ME, since I indeed haven't seen any proof nor couldn't find any info on the internet on how to see the proof :)

Comment: The problem is that the proofs of these things are things that take books to explain. Or white papers. They're not the sort of stuff that can easily be explained on a Q+A website, nor even in a blog post or two. And actually understanding the proofs takes a great deal of learning. You're asking too much to expect a satisfying answer on SO.

Comment: You're right, but I am not trying drill down into the subject. I just want to use some tool, or something that will show me that communication is secure, message is encrypted, etc... Maybe I am missing something ;)

Comment: So, we give you a simple tool that tells you that communication is secure, message is encrypted, etc. Why do you trust that tool?

Answer (score 2):

Well, when I want to see all messages exchanged with WCF, I usually use this technique.

Exemple: The following example is a RESTFull call in WCF but the technique works for all kind of communication done with WCF.

```
 using (WebChannelFactory<ITestService> cf = new WebChannelFactory<ITestService>(new Uri("http://172.80.1.235/")))
                {
                    ((WebHttpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
                    cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new RestMessageInspector());
                    ITestService channel = cf.CreateChannel();
                    TestJob job = channel.CancelJob(id, new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<cancel></cancel>")));
                }
```

In this exemple we can see **cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new RestMessageInspector());** which will enable you to follow all communication.

The class RestMessageInspector needs to be created as follow: (It needs to implement two interfaces IClientMessageInspector and IEndpointBehavior)

```
public class RestMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector, IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {

        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {

        }
    }
```

Then with breaks points you will be able to follow the whole process ;) and to see all messages !

In conclusion the main point is to include an extra behavior implementing those interfaces.

I hope it will help you!